# How to appropriate a function into a class in Python

Tags: python, class, self

I am new to programming. In Coursera, I learnt to write a script that decides whether a sentence is palindrome or not. But it does not have a class. I need to appropriate this function into one with a class and self:

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):

new_string = ""
reverse_string = ""

for letter in input_string:
     
    if not letter == " ":
        new_string = letter + new_string
        reverse_string = reverse_string + letter

if reverse_string.lower() == new_string.lower():
    return True
return False

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even"))
print(is_palindrome("abc"))
print(is_palindrome("kayak"))
```

But when I tried to do something like this:

```
class cis_palindrome:
  def is_palindrome(self, string):
    self.string = string

    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""

    for letter in string:
        
        if not letter == " ":
            new_string = letter + new_string
            reverse_string = reverse_string + letter

    if reverse_string.lower() == new_string.lower():
        return True

print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even"))
print(is_palindrome("abc"))
print(is_palindrome("kayak"))
```

It doesn't work. And I really tried to understand the concept of self and **init**, but the thing is that I could not find any examples in which self is replaced by the string that is not assigned before, and printed with the new input, like in these print examples.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between a *function* and a *method* (which is what you are defining `is_palindrome` in your second code)?  Can you provide details as to in what way this "doesn't work"?

Comment: your problem is NOT `self` and `__init__` but first you have to create instance of class `instance = cis_palindrome()` and later use it `instance.is_palindrome(...)`

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) - you better spend some time with the tutorial in the Python docs. More likely than not you should start at the beginning rather than jump in at the class section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is NOT `self` and `__init__` but you simply use class in wrong way.

First you have to create instance of class

```
instance = cis_palindrome()
```

and later use it

```
print( instance.is_palindrome(...) )
```

Eventually you can do it in one line - but this can be useful when you have to use it only once

```
print( cis_palindrome().is_palindrome(...) )
```

---

Full working code:

You don't use `self.string` so I removed it.

There is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - it helps to recognize class in code.

```py
class CisPalindrome:   # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes

  def is_palindrome(self, string):
    
    new_string = ""
    reverse_string = ""

    for letter in string:
        
        if not letter == " ":
            new_string = letter + new_string
            reverse_string = reverse_string + letter

    if reverse_string.lower() == new_string.lower():
        return True

instance = CisPalindrome()

print(instance.is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even"))
print(instance.is_palindrome("abc"))
print(instance.is_palindrome("kayak"))
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to use `self` and `__init__` then you can do

```
class CisPalindrome:
    
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
        
    def is_palindrome(self):

        new_string = ""
        reverse_string = ""

        for letter in self.string:
            if not letter == " ":
                new_string = letter + new_string
                reverse_string = reverse_string + letter

        if reverse_string.lower() == new_string.lower():
            return True

print(CisPalindrome("Never Odd or Even").is_palindrome())
print(CisPalindrome("abc").is_palindrome())
print(CisPalindrome("kayak").is_palindrome())
```

---

**BTW:**

Lines

```
    if reverse_string.lower() == new_string.lower():
        return True
```

You can reduce to

```
    return reverse_string.lower() == new_string.lower()
```

because `==` gives `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your class to be able to use its methods (in your case, the `is_palindrome` method).

```py
class cis_palindrome:

  def __init__(self, ...):
    # Your init

  def is_palindrome(self, string):
    # Your algorithm

# Initialization of the cis_palindrome class
pal = cis_palindrome()

# Call the is_palindrome method
result = pal.is_palindrome("kayak")
print(result)
```